# Would renters insurance cover this scenario?

Tags: united-states, insurance, rental-property

This is US based. I have renters insurance and the coverage overview is as follows:

- Personal Property
- Loss of Use
- Personal Liability
- Medical.

I have read my policy, but I do not believe the following is covered:

**My** appliance *failed*. This resulted in damage to the flooring of the apartment.

What part of renters insurance, *if any*, would apply? What wording should I look for?

I have found theft, and medical, but nothing for my property damaging the unit.

Comment: If your landlord finds you personally liable for the repair costs, presumably "personal liability" would apply, but ... IANAL.

Comment: Liability usually covers accidental damage to landlord / other tenants' property caused by you or your property, so that's where I'd expect to find coverage for the damaged floor.  Loss of use is basically you being unable to use your apartment and personal property covers replacing your stuff that's damaged / stolen in a "covered loss" (see your insurance for details, typically stuff like theft/fire/vandalism).

Comment: Is it YOUR appliance, or is it an appliance that your landlord provided?

Comment: Also you may have gross neglect. How can a failed appliance damage the flooring? Washing machine? Should be on a floor that can handle it. Did your toaster start burning or something else that could not be expected?

Comment: @TomTom Some kitchens have hardwood floors, so if a refrigerator or dishwasher fails it could damage the floors.

Comment: You can let your insurance agent know what happened and ask if you're covered. Obviously, they're more likely to say no, but that would be your first step.

Comment: We need to know what type of appliance and what you mean by "fail"?